# Drupal 6 js optimization

Tags: performance, drupal-6, file-get-contents

I have a problem when I try to activate the js file optimization in performance.

I have this message : « warning: file_get_contents(sites/default/files/languages/user_060260a4795d7a717208da40cdaf54f9.js) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*************/www/includes/common.inc on line 2520. » (************** here is my site name)

In the languages file I only have fr_13212a0121a0a65154021a51.js and it appears that for example in **user**_060260a4795d7a717208da40cdaf54f9.js user seams to be the url ex: xyz.com/user of the previous page.

For example if I am on xyz.com/hello and I change page, I have the message with a file named : **hello**_16511fqf165f6511q65qfqf654654.js.

Does someone know where the problem comes from?

Thank you

Comment: Hi I find a solution for this problem.

Just have to follow these steps:

-1) download https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2009-09-12%20tweak_locale_js_0.zip
-2) enable the custom module
-3) navigate to admin/settings/language#js-translations
-4) expand "JavaScript translations" fieldset
-5) use either "Invalidate js translations" or "Rebuild js translations" buttons

Thanks to arhak on https://www.drupal.org/node/338630#comment-2035162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I find a solution for this problem. Just have to follow these steps:

-1) download drupal.org/files/issues/2009-09-12%20tweak_locale_js_0.zip
-2) enable the custom module
-3) navigate to admin/settings/language#js-translations
-4) expand "JavaScript translations" fieldset
-5) use either "Invalidate js translations" or "Rebuild js translations" buttons.

Thanks to arhak on drupal.org/node/338630#comment-2035162